# Closest neighbor to any point (other than itself) in a 2D plane

Tags: python, distance, nearest-neighbor

Given a 2D plane and N points (n1=(x1,y1), n2=(x2,y2)..., nN=(xN,yN)), what is a fast (O(n) or better) algorithm that will find the closest neighbor of any point (e.g. n1 closest neighbor is n3, n2 closest neighbor is n4). I was thinking about storing it in a dictionary where the keys are the points, and the values are the neighbors.

There seem to be quite a lot of similar questions on SO, but I couldn't find any code in Python or answers that are not in other languages.

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck.  Simply cycle through each of the other points.  Compute the distance.  Remember the least.  This is **O(n)**.  Data structure access is the least of your worries; the distance computation is almost certainly your bottleneck.

Comment: I guess I'm quite new to time complexity. Do I need to calculate the distance from 1 point to any other point (say, in a 2D table), and then just find the smallest distance? I was thinking that it will be faster if I could just find the nearest neighbor without actually calculating every distance

Comment: Sounds like you are dealing with k-nearest neighbors algorithm. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306122/nearest-neighbor-search-in-octree) and [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00138-017-0889-4)

Comment: Yes, that's the algorithm.  For arbitrary input points, there is nothing faster than finding every distance.  You can speed up the process a tiny amount by computing simpler distances and discarding obvious misfits, but the problem is inherently **O(n)**.

Comment: If you are going to find more than a single nearest neighbor, *then* you may have some way to make your long-term methodology better than **O(n*m)**, where `m` is the quantity of inquiries you make.  Research "nearest neighbor".

Comment: I see. Is there any chance you could tell me how it's O(n)? If I'm iterating through every point, and then calculating the distance from that point to any other point it seems like the complexity is O(n^2). 
Also, I was thinking that maybe there's a way to extend a "cycle" from any point until it finds the closest neighbor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution that can yield better results than O(n) on average is using a **k-d tree** for storing the points. building the tree has a worst case complexity O(nlogn). after that searching is on average **O(logn)** and worst case O(n) (usually for points away from all the other data).

Also you might be interested in LSH or locality sensitive hashing while it is an approximation approach meaning you won't always get the right answer, for high dimensional data it provides an important speedup with complexity being closely related to the parameters chosen.

Comment: In regards to trees, I'm wondering if using "implicit octrees" as Sai mentioned would be faster. I still don't know how to code it though : )

Comment: @MaxK if speed is the matter python is much more of a bottleneck than the choice between the 2 but keep in mind octrees is a data structure for 3-D data only. while k-d trees are k dimensions meaning in your case you just need k=2 for your data. Also k-d trees are used in many applications and many libraries for them exist already so the implementation then for you has to do with high level logic instead of managing the trees

Comment: Oh those are really good points that I wasn't aware of. So if I understand correctly, my time complexity will be O(nlogn) to build the tree? Using k-d tree. Wasn't sure how that's better results on average than O(n)

Comment: @MaxK O(n) is the complexity for finding the closest neighboors for one element, if you need to do a search for k elements it's then O(k*n) and if you want to do this for n elements it's then O(n^2), but with k-d trees this is reduced to O(nlogn + klogn) or if you need n elements O(nlogn) which is better than O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

For a given a point P, simple solution:

- Calculate P's distance from all other points, this is done with O(n) time complexity.
- Save them as list of tuples (or similar data structure), the tuples of (point, distance from P).
- One walk over the list can yield you the top K closest points, in O(n) time complexity.

A second solution that will cost more in space complexity (O(n^2)) and maintenance over time, but will  shorten finding the K nearest neighbors:

- Keeping a dictionary from each point to a **ordered list** (or similar data structure) of points by their distance - building this table once is O(n^2 * log(n)).
- Finding K closest points is O(k) - dictionary access + copying k elements from ordered list.
- Overhead in time complexity would be in adding a new point or removing an old one in a manner that will keep this data structure valid - O(n*log(n)) in both.

The solution you choose should be on what you want to optimize

Comment: But since I have to do it for every point (not just for point P), won't the complexity be at least O(n^2)?

Comment: In that case yes. Because there are n^2 distances between every 2 points.

Comment: After some research I found this good and comprehensive [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/k-nearest-neighbors-computational-complexity-502d2c440d5) that offers different design implementations and their complexity, is it helpful?

Comment: Potentially actually! Looks like the brute force will be the fastest. I'm not sure how is it: Prediction time complexity: O(k * n * d). Since it's calculating the distance from every point to every other point. If that's correct (and I still don't see how), then that will imply that it can solve my problem in O(n) since my k=1, d=2. Any idea how it's possible?

Comment: Looks like the brute force is for a single given point you want to classify, not all of them, i.e. my first simple solution. what are your settings?

Comment: Oh I see. Well, I need to get the closest neighbor of every point. I've been reading about this quite a bit now and I don't see a way to get it without iterating through every single point which will make it O(n^2). @jimakr suggestion was to use k-d trees and that will reduce it to O(nlogn) which is still not as good as I was hoping.

Comment: @MaxK it's impossible to get lower complexity for this than O(nlogn) since you are essentially trying to calculate something for every element in the list with all the others, this is the same thing a sorting algorithm would do except instead of calculating between pairs, it would compare them. But in this complexity we are counting the number elements get accessed so essentially the problems are equivalent, and it's mathematically proven than O(nlog) for such operations is the lowest possible complexity

Comment: @jimakr I see. Okay, that makes a lot of sense. I guess I was hoping that there's a way to get the neighbor of every element without actually comparing all the elements. The only thing that came to my mind was creating some circle (2D plane), and extending it from the point I'm looking for until it reaches a single point. But I couldn't find anything like that

Comment: the circle idea would actually perform a lot worse than O(nlogn), in each iteration of it you would have to check if any point is on the circle or inside (you would miss some of them since the step size won't divide every pair distance perfectly so you also check inside)that means checking actually all the points so you get O(n) for checking, if we assume you get it on first try every time you then have O(n^2) for all the elemnts. Real world performance would be far worse though due to the many iterations for every element. If any answer solved your question don't forget to accept it