# What is the high level pseudo code for searching all the neighbours within a radius r of a query point in a kd-tree

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, language-agnostic, kdtree

This [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) has high level descriptions and pseudocode for most of the operations one can do on a kd-tree.

For example it describes how to initialize it:

```
function kdtree (list of points pointList, int depth)
{
    // Select axis based on depth so that axis cycles through all valid values
    var int axis := depth mod k;

    // Sort point list and choose median as pivot element
    select median by axis from pointList;

    // Create node and construct subtree
    node.location := median;
    node.leftChild := kdtree(points in pointList before median, depth+1);
    node.rightChild := kdtree(points in pointList after median, depth+1);
    return node;
}
```

Notice the above is not a specific programming langugage, just pseudo-code, which is what I am looking for (I want to udnerstand the algorithm, not necessarily implement it).

That page however does not explain, at all, how one would find all neighbours within a radius of a query point, but this is a common operation for kd-trees.

Said otherwise, assume one has an already initialized kd tree in some magical language. One coud do the following to find the set of all points in the tree that are 0.1 units away from the query point `(pi, e, epsilon)`

```
kd_tree.find_neighbours((pi, e, epsilon), 0.1)
```

If we anted the nearest point, instead of all points within a radius we could follow the steps described by the section `Nearest neighbour search`. However that is a different goal and a different algorithm.

What's the algorithm for finding points within a radius in a kd tree?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306122/nearest-neighbor-search-in-octree/41306992#41306992

Comment: If it helps, here is an [actual implementation in Java](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes/blob/083e190b2b4d8989fa3e04592d0fb03d6260368b/src/main/java/org/tinspin/index/kdtree/KDTree.java#L500)

Answer (score 0):

Implemented it based partially on a comment and partially on scrapping the web for answers.

The high level idea is, you agument the KD tree with a bounding box. I.e. every node in teh tree stores the axis aligned bounding box of the points contained inside that node.

When creating the tree it's super simple, initialize the tree as normal (see the wiki article on the topic) except you do the following:

- Before initializing the nodes, create a bounding box for the root node.
- Each new node inherits `half` the BB of its parent the left child has the BB half to the left of the median along the current axis, the right child has it the other half.

Finding all neighbours within `radius` distance of a query point goes as follows:

- Start at the root node and check if the BB distance between the query point and the box is less than the radius, if it is push teh children to the stack.
- Recurse until the current node is at the maximum depth, if it is maximum depth and it is within radius of the query point, mark it for processing.

At this point wou know all leafs with potential candidates so just iterate over their span checking individual points, all points that are within redius are added to a list and bingo.

Here's a C++ implemntation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include "Eigen/Dense"

template <typename Vec>
struct AABB
{
    Vec min;
    Vec max;
};

template <typename Vec>
float AABBDistance(const AABB<Vec>& bb, const Vec& point)
{
    const float width = bb.max[0] - bb.min[0];
    const float height = bb.max[1] - bb.min[1];
    const float depth = bb.max[2] - bb.min[2];

    Vec center = (bb.max + bb.min) / 2;

    const float dx = std::max(abs(point[0] - center[0]) - width / 2.f, 0.f);
    const float dy = std::max(abs(point[1] - center[1]) - height / 2.f, 0.f);
    const float dz = std::max(abs(point[2] - center[2]) - depth / 2.f, 0.f);

    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
}

template <typename Vec>
AABB<Vec> ComputeBoundingBox(const std::vector<Vec>& points, uint start, uint end)
{
    float min_x = points[0].x();
    float max_x = points[0].x();
    float min_y = points[0].y();
    float max_y = points[0].y();
    float min_z = points[0].z();
    float max_z = points[0].z();

    for(uint i=start; i<end; i++)
    {
        auto& point = points[i];

        min_x = std::min(point.x(), min_x);
        max_x = std::max(point.x(), max_x);

        min_y = std::min(point.y(), min_y);
        max_y = std::max(point.y(), max_y);

        min_z = std::min(point.z(), min_z);
        max_z = std::max(point.z(), max_z);
    }

    return {{min_x, min_y, min_z}, {max_x, max_y, max_z}};
}

struct KDNode
{
    uint depth;
    uint left_child;
    uint right_child;
    std::pair<uint, uint> span;
    float median_value;
};

template <typename Vec>
class KDTree
{
public:
    uint max_depth;
    std::vector<Vec> points;
    std::vector<KDNode> nodes;
    std::vector<AABB<Vec>> bounding_boxes;

public:
    KDTree(const std::vector<Vec> &points, uint max_depth);

    std::vector<Vec> FindNeighbours(const Vec& point, float radius) const;
};

template <typename Vec>
KDTree<Vec>::KDTree(const std::vector<Vec> &point_list, uint m_depth)
    : max_depth(m_depth - 1), points(point_list)
{
    std::vector<uint> stack = {0};

    const auto node = KDNode(0,
                             0,
                             0,
                             {0, points.size()},
                             0);
    nodes = {node};
    bounding_boxes = {ComputeBoundingBox(points, 0, points.size())};

    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        uint node_id = stack.back();
        auto &node = nodes[node_id];
        auto& bounding_box = bounding_boxes[node_id];
        stack.pop_back();

        auto [start, end] = node.span;
        uint axis = node.depth % 3;

        auto order_by_axis = [&axis](Vec v1, Vec v2)
        { return v1[axis] < v2[axis]; };

        std::sort(points.begin() + start, points.begin() + end, order_by_axis);

        Assert(end >= start, "");
        uint median = start + (end - start) / 2;
        node.median_value = points[median][axis];

        if (node.depth < max_depth)
        {
            AABB<Vec> bb_left = bounding_box;
            AABB<Vec> bb_right = bounding_box;
            bb_left.max[axis] = node.median_value;
            bb_right.min[axis] = node.median_value;

            node.left_child = nodes.size();
            node.right_child = nodes.size() + 1;
            const uint depth = node.depth;
            stack.push_back(nodes.size());
            nodes.push_back({depth + 1, 0, 0, {start, median}, 0});
            bounding_boxes.push_back(bb_left);
            stack.push_back(nodes.size());
            nodes.push_back({depth + 1, 0, 0, {median, end}, 0});
            bounding_boxes.push_back(bb_right);
        }
    }
}

template <typename Vec>
std::vector<Vec> KDTree<Vec>::FindNeighbours(const Vec& point, float radius) const
{
    std::vector<uint> stack = {0};
    std::vector<Vec> neighbours;

    std::vector<uint> nodes_to_check;
    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        uint node_id = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();

        const auto& node = nodes[node_id];
        const auto& bb = bounding_boxes[node_id];

        float distance = AABBDistance(bb, point);
        if(distance > radius) continue;

        if(node.depth == max_depth)
        {
            nodes_to_check.push_back(node_id);
        }
        else
        {
            stack.push_back(node.left_child);
            stack.push_back(node.right_child);
        }
    }

    for(uint node_id : nodes_to_check)
    {
        auto& node = nodes[node_id];
        for(uint i=node.span.first; i < node.span.second; i++)
            if((point - points[i]).norm() < radius)
                neighbours.push_back(points[i]);
    }

    return neighbours;
}
```